# Better formatting for HTML tags with Vetur?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier, vetur

I noticed that `prettier` is now used by Vetur to format the HTML part of Vue files. I don't always understand the way it is formatted:

```
<b-button v-else pill variant="primary" @click="submit"
  >Finish</b-button
>
```

If I add just one `class` element it goes:

```
<b-button
  v-else
  pill
  class="pb-2"
  variant="primary"
  @click="submit"
  >Finish</b-button
>
```

However, since my editor is more than 100 chars wide, it would make it legit to format it as:

```
<b-button v-else pill class="pb-2" variant="primary" @click="submit">
  Finish
</b-button>
```

I looked at the [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) of Prettier, but I didn't find any relevant configuration settings for this matter.

How can tell my vscode formatter to format HTML tags as wanted?

In my `.prettierrc.json` I have:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prettier offers you options for both:

- printWidth for the line length https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width
- htmlWhitespaceSensitivity for handling of brackets https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity

To get your desired output, you would probably need:

```js
{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
}
```

By default the `htmlWhitespaceSensivity` is set to `'css'`, because:

> as you may notice during daily HTML works, the following two cases won't produce the same output:
>
> 1<b> 2 </b>3 => 1 2 3
>
> 1<b>2</b>3   => 123
>
> This happens because whitespace is significant in inline elements.

from : https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting

Comment: It doesn't seem `printwidth` works. I set it to `1000` and still, the HTML entities are wrapped across several lines.

Comment: Oops. It is a typo, should be `printWidth`.